# arrange list elements horizontal with overflow

Tags: html, css

i have 7 li in the ul box and each one have 20% of width and that mean it need 140% of width
so i have to set up this with css and horizontal overflow.
but in my case it show only 4 li and others are hidden without scroll!
what is the solution to show all li in one line!?

sample: http://jsfiddle.net/2DbnS/

```
<style>
#list1 > li {
list-style-type: none;width:20%;
height:195px;border:1px solid gray;
float:left;margin:2px;text-align: center;
}
</style>
<ul style='border:1px solid red;width:90%;height:215px;overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:hidden;' id=list1>

<li>
<b>ocr 1</b><br />
</li>
<li >
<b>ocr 100</b><br />
</li>
<li >
<b>ocr 1000</b><br />
</li>
<li >
<b>ocr 2000</b><br />
</li>
<li >
<b>ocr 5000</b><br />
</li>
<li >
<b>ocr 10000</b><br />
</li>    
<li >
<b>ocr 15000</b><br />
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `float` from the `LI` and update your CSS to include the following. This will set your `LI` elements as inline elements so they will follow on from each other and setting `white-space:nowrap;` on the `UL` will prevent them from wrapping and create the overflow behaviour you require.

```
   #list1 {
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
    #list1 > li {
        display:inline-block;
        ...
```

Here is an update of your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2DbnS/1/) including some further tweaks such as removing the padding from the `UL` to shift all the boxes to the left.

Comment: this fixed but all li are aligned right and i got 20px free and the left side of my ul,how can i fix this!?

Comment: @peimanF.please seee my revised [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2DbnS/1/) which removes the space to the left.

Answer (score 1):

```
#list1 {
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding:0;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:90%;
    height:215px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
#list1 > li {
    list-style-type:none;
    width:20%;
    height:195px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    margin:2px;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

And some mistakes that 7 of 20% width li elements do not mean that it need 140% of the total width. ul element padding, li element margin, border etc should also be considered.